# Returning random numbers instead of 5.1 to be specific

Tags: c

Below is a code for Bounding Phase method which returns midpoint of the limits. But it is not returning the value to main() function.
the lines where the problem is arising is commented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float func(float x)
{
    float f = (pow(x,2) + (54 / x));        
    return f;
}

float bPhase(float x0, float delta)
{
    float x1 , f0, f1, f2, a, b, mPt;
    int k, p;
    k = 0;
    p = 0;

    f0 = func(x0 - delta);
    p++;
    f1 = func(x0);
    p++;
    f2 = func(x0 + delta);
    p++;

    if(f0 <= f1 && f1 <= f2)
        delta = -1 * delta;
    else
        delta = delta;

    printf("%f %f %f\n", f0, f1, f2);

    x1 = x0 + pow(2,k) * delta;
    while(func(x1) < func(x0))
    {
        k++;
        a = x0;
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = x1 + pow(2,k) * delta;     
        b = x1;
        printf("%f %f %f\n", func(a),func(x0),func(b));
        p++;
    }

    printf("Minimum lies between %.3f and %.3f", a, b);
    printf("\nIteration no: %d\n", k+1);
    printf("Total no. of function evaluations: %d\n", p);

    mPt = ((a+b)/2.0); 
    printf("%f\n", mPt);                                //Here prints 5.1

    return mPt;                                         //Should return 5.1, but not returning
}

int main(void)
{

    float x0, mPt;
    float delta;

    printf("Enter initial guess: ");        // guess is .6
    scanf("%f", &x0);
    printf("Enter increment: ");            // 0.5
    scanf("%f", &delta);

    bPhase(x0, delta);

    printf("\n%f\n", mPt);          //should print 5.1 but prints random

return 0;
}
```

Function bPhase is not returning anything. Please help. Main function is not receiving the value of mPt from bPhase function.
A newbie here. Thank you.

Comment: `bPhase(x0, delta);` -> `mPt = bPhase(x0, delta);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable in `main` called `mPt` and a variable in `bPhase` called `mPt`.  These are **not** the same variable.  Different variables may exist with the same name in different scopes.

Also, when `bPhase` returns you don't do anything with the return value.  You need to assign it to `mPt`.  Then you'll see the value you expect.

```
mPt = bPhase(x0, delta);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable named `mPt` in your `main` function, but you don't assign it the value returned from `bPhase`, so it's uninitialized.

Do this:

```
    mPt = bPhase(x0, delta);
```

I would also read about C's [scope rules](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) since the impression I got is that you think that the variable `mPt` in `bPhase` is the same as the variable `mPt` in `main`.